# iSNS Best Practices

Tags: iscsi, windows-server-2012-r2

I am looking into deploying an iSNS server to simplify deployment of a new iSCSI infrastructure for a client of mine. I feel that I understand what iSNS does and how to configure it, but I'd like some insight into best practice deployment scenarios, specifically:

- Is there any implication when installing iSNS services on a virtual machine?
- Ideally, I'd like to pair up iSNS with other services to economize on resources. What would be the best service(s) to match up with iSNS? I was thinking that DNS (Domain Controller) would not be bad since iSNS is essentially DNS for iSCSI.
- Is there value in deploying multiple iSNS servers?

Any insight would be appreciated. I'd love for someone with an iSNS infrastructure to share experiences regarding their deployment. Thanks!